# When a 1D linear object is squeezed along this straight line, does it break and become 2D?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

There is a straight wire that has minimum thickness (thus I say it's one-dimensional). If you squeeze this straight wire from its two end, and the forces are strictly along this straight line (like in the picture below), then is that possible it breaks and go out of this straight line?
I don't think that's possible, because there is no force that points in any other orientation than the straight line. But my friend points out that if it puckers or breaks and goes out of the line, the potential energy is lowered, and it is lowered faster than in the case that the wire just contracts. So he thinks the forces will finally drive the wire out of the straight line. Who's correct? And is there a difference between macroscope and microscope in this case?
 [image]

Comment: This seems entirely to depend on your model of the "wire".

Comment: So what factors of wire will lead to the wire puckering into 2D?@ACuriousMind

Comment: If the wire is __perfectly__ straight it won't bend. But any deviation, no matter how small, will make the wire buckle. Perfect straightness is not physically possible. So for a perfect wire you are right but in reality you can't have such a wire.

Comment: @user3502079 Yes I mean it's strictly in a straight line. I'm talking about a model not the reality.

Comment: @user3502079 My friend says things are always trying to lower their potential energy and thus it will pucker. How do you refute this statement?

Comment: @XYZ Compare it to a ball that lies on a parabola shaped hill. The hill has the shape $y=-x^2$ and the ball is located at exactly $x=0$. If you give the ball a tiny nudge it will quickly accelerate (the system tries to lower its potential energy), but if no nudge happens it will just stay there, because the slope of the potential is zero. Just because lower potential energy is available doesn't necessarily mean the energy will always be lowered. It is a good rule of thumb though.

Comment: @user3502079 That's a perfect example. Thanks.

Comment: This is a cool example of [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking). Check it out!